# receives a string and return with only english words

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

here is my code

```py
def words_only(sentence):
    wordlist1 = sentence.split()
    wordlist2 = []
    for word in wordlist1:
        modified = ''
        for char in word:
            if char in '_-!,.?":;0123456789':
                char = ''
            modified += char
        wordlist2.append(modified)
    return wordlist2
```

And the description is: words_only receives a string as an argument and returns a list with all the words that were in the sentence. For the purposes of this functions, words are a sequence of only letters (either lower case or upper case
the input is

```
words_only("two-fold will count as 2 words.")
```

However, I failed the last test. my output is

```
['twofold', 'will', 'count', 'as', '', 'words']
```

the correct output should be

```
["two", "fold", "will", "count", "as", "words"]
```

> how can I fix my code so that the colon will disappear and "two-fold" will count as 2 words? And there is also an empty string that caused the error.

Comment: Please paste the code here

Comment: Please [edit] the question and paste the code

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you have a word that is only formed by the symbols/numbers in your list it will give you an empty string, in the image of your output it seems that you should not add this empty string to your final list. You can fix it by adding an if statement before wordlist2.append(modified_w).

write:
if modified_w:
wordlist2.append(modified_w)

and empty string is considered False so it will not add it, whereas if the symbol/number is within a word it will remove it from the word and then add the corrected word

Answer (score 0):

When using Python, you should utilize its features as much as possible  - namely, list comprehension and built-in functions:

```
[word for word in sentence.split() if word.isalpha()]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would happen is because you didn't divide the word that conclude str '-'

You can change the code

```
def words_only(sentence):
    wordlist1 = sentence.split()
    wordlist2 = []
    for word in wordlist1:
        modified = ''
        for char in word:
            if char in '-_0123456789,.[];{}':
                if modified: wordlist2.append(modified)
                modified = ''
            else:
                modified += char

        if modified: wordlist2.append(modified)
    return wordlist2
```

hope this will be helpful!

[image]

Comment: You made a mistake. ```char == '_-.123456789'``` should be ```char  in  '_-.123456789'```, how can a single character be equal to that? It is always False

Comment: can you please tell me what does this line means? "if modified: word_list2.append(modified)"

Comment: Well it works for me at least, I've post my code and the result, 'if modified word_list2.append(modified)' means if modified's value is not empty nor None, then add that value to the word_list2.